# Custom Timing Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand `CustomEvent` in `Javascript`, but I don't think I am in the right mindset.

Is `CustomEvent` an alternative to time-sensitive actions such as changes to `dataset` or other properties in the `DOM`?

Take this non-sensical situation for example: Let's say every 5 seconds I have a `div` that will change color and I want to display a modal window with a notification each time that the `div` is a new color.

Can `CustomEvent` be used as a listener for the modal window so that it knows when the `div` has changed color or is this only possible with `setInveral`/`setTimeout`?

Comment: to me, CustomEvent is more about recycling the addEventListener() interaction mechanism for non UI events, much like an EventEmitter in nodejs.

Comment: ok. so I guess I'm asking if there is a way to listen for changes in the `DOM` besides `setInterval`?

Comment: There are mutation events and mutation observers, but last I checked, neither was supported to a production-level.

Comment: it seems like you are trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist. Whatever logic updates the div should also send out an event that you can listen for.

Comment: how would you "send out an event"? and what would listen for it?

Comment: This is usually solved without events and custom event triggers, you add a callback to whenever the modal is closed, or an input element in the modal has changed, and then you change the color, it's not rocket science ?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but in this case the modal and `div` would be two separate entities. Could they communicate with a callback?

Comment: Just check out how JQuery is designed, you often pass a callback function as a parameter. The callback function -is- the communication. Using this simple third party javascript library you can setup a global custom events as an alternative, but for most cases that can be overkill as already said: https://github.com/mmikowski/jquery.event.gevent

Comment: Thanks. That cleared things up a bit. Yes, that would be overkill indeed. Just a little fuzzy between events and callbacks.